# What can I improve on my iOS PDF class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

This is the first PDF class I have made for the iOS using code from Apple's samples.  There could easily be stuff here wrong that I am missing.

I intend this to get images out of for a layer, for example:

```
image.contents = (id)[self.test imageForPage: 3 size: CGSizeMake(4*dpc, 2*dpc)].CGImage;
```

Here is this hopefully decent code.  Any suggestions are welcome.

```
@interface PDFDocument : NSObject {
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfFile;
}

- (id) initWithURL: (NSURL*) url;
- (UIImage*) imageForPage: (size_t) pageno size: (CGSize) size;
- (CGSize) sizeOfPage: (size_t) pageno;

@end

@implementation PDFDocument

- (id) initWithURL: (NSURL*) url {
    if ([super init])
    {
        // Open PDF
        CGPDFDocumentRef doc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);

        if (doc == NULL)
            @throw @"PDF File does not exist.";

        pdfFile = doc;

    }
    return self;
}

- (UIImage*) imageForPage: (size_t) pageno size: (CGSize) size {
    if (pdfFile) {
        // Get First Page
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfFile, pageno);

        if (page == NULL)
            @throw @"Page does not exist.";

        // Get Page Size
        CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);

        // Start Drawing Context to Render PDF
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        CGRect u = { {0, 0}, size};

        CGContextFillRect(context, u);
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, NO);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        // Scale PDF
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, size.width / cropBox.size.width, size.height / cropBox.size.height);

        // Flip Context to render PDF correctly
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, cropBox.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // must retain?

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;

    }
    return nil;
}

- (CGSize) sizeOfPage: (size_t) pageno {
    if (pdfFile) {
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfFile, pageno);

        if (page == NULL)
            @throw @"Page does not exist";

        CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);

        return cropBox.size;
    }

    @throw @"No document loaded.";
}

@end
```

Comment: I have encountered PDF files where the text is written in landscape but the page width and height will tell you that the page is in portrait. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file will be in landscape. I had to add special handling for files like those. Unfortunately, I don't have my code with me right now so I can't share, but I believe you're missing that part.

Comment: Something like this? http://ipdfdev.com/2011/03/23/display-a-pdf-page-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/

Comment: Yeah, something like that. But I remember mine to be much simpler, like ~8 additional lines only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One immediate change I'd make is how you're handling errors.  While `try-catch` blocks are extremely common in other programming languages, I actually don't see them all that very often in Objective-C.

That doesn't mean we won't have errors.  It just means error handling is typically handled differently in my experience with Objective-C.  Just take a look at some of the Foundation methods as example:

```
stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:
```

You can send `nil` as the argument for the `error`, but otherwise, you send the method an `NSError` object, and when the method returns, if there was an error, you can check the object to find out what it was.  In the case of an `init` method, if an error occurred, you'd also want to return `nil` as well as loading the error description in the passed error object.

---

For completeness, it seems like it might be a good idea to create a corresponding `PDFPage` class.  And instead of `imageForPage:size:` being called over and over to create pages, the end user would create instances of `PDFPage`.  The `PDFDocument` in turn isn't much more than an array of `PDFPages` with some logic for adding a single page, array of pages, remove pages, from front, back, specific index, etc.

Comment: I never liked that kind of error control, although now I would never use exceptions like that either.